# python package usage tracking mechanism

Tags: python

I am trying to give value to a certain package and library by building some usage stats. This package is written in python and invoked/imported by users on remote machines/cluster

What we are trying to do is to set up a certain tracking mechanism that will register or log every time someone imports the package and ideally how long he used it.

I can think of a a normal logger that will log at import time of the package and will log when the process closes/dies/exits using atexit function.

```
# let's import the package here
import package
# at this stage the package automaticaly logs something like the following in a certain file
# os.getpid() | getpass.getuser() | os.uname() | importing package time.time()

# when the process or session is closed. ataxit will execute the same function that will log the following
# os.getpid() | getpass.getuser() | os.uname() | ataxit process time.time()
```

This way this log file can be analyzed later for info about package usage.

Now, I wonder if there is another more elegant or standard solution to do all of that.

Comment: Is this an internal only package? I'm pretty sure that no one will use a package which starts reporting data to another external source like this.

Comment: Oh yeah absolutely. I agree with you, this is for internal usage only. BU needs to give valuation for the implementation by counting internal users and time of usage.

Comment: This doesn't so much "give value" as measure usage. The idea makes me wonder if the package loader has a verbose enough switch to do this for you.

Comment: Read about import hooks. They exist in both Python 2 and 3 but differ somehow.

Comment: As a warning: What about devs working with this package? Every import while running unit test could inflate your count.

Answer (score 1):

If you want centralized logging, you should probably send the usage statistics to a remote server, e.g. with the http-logger to logstash. Could be easier to maintain than trying to find dozens of logfiles.

I would be loath to use something like atexit, there are lots of scenarios where this function will never run (yanking the cord, abnormal interpreter shutdown etc.). I would probably start a separate thread which sends a regular ping while your module is imported. Use some log aggregating at you collection server to compute the total time run. You would need to generate a unique ID at import time, but that is easy.

Lastly: The python logging module is ...not really good. Could be easier just to build a small function which sends your logs to the desired server. I spend several hours sending a log to logstash, so I am pretty biased against the logging module.